# How can I replace my site's domain name on search engines with its business name?

Tags: seo, wordpress, meta-tags, yoast, google-search-site-name

I'm building a site and I've noticed that when I search my site's name on Google, unlike other sites my website's URL is displayed instead of the business title.

Can somebody please help me figure this out?

I've built my site using Wordpress and my SEO tool is Yoast.

Image for context:

[image: google search results for National Leak Pros]

Answer (score 6):

You can make a strong suggestion on what Google should use by implementing **[Website Schema](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names#website)**. This isn't a directive - Google is under no obligation to use your suggestion - but it usually works if you're patient and persistent. I've found frequently changing the exact text of these tags doesn't go down well at all.

Other methods for getting Google to pick up the name are by putting it as the **Home Page title**, having it follow page titles (My Article - **BrandName**), used in the **H1 for the main page** and placing it in the [opengraph tags](https://ogp.me/) for **og:site_name**.

Do all of those and Google usually picks it up in a few weeks. It can fluctuate but the longer you have this information up the stronger the suggestion is.

Quoted from *[Provide a site name to Google Search - Google Search Central](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names)*:

> ### How site names in Google Search are created
>
> Google's generation of site names on the Google Search results page is completely automated and takes into account both the content of a site and references to it that appear on the web. The goal of the site name is to best represent and describe the source of each result.
>
> Google Search uses a number of sources from a site's home page to automatically determine site names, including:
>
> - [`WebSite` structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names#website)
> - Content in `<title>` elements
> - Heading elements, such as `<h1>` elements
> - `og:site_name`
>
> While we can't manually change site names for individual sites, we're always working to make them as accurate as possible. You can help improve the quality of the site name that's displayed for your page by adding [`WebSite` structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names#website).

Comment: The portion on website schema may be correct.  But the rest has not worked on any of my sites.  Have you got a citation for it ?

Comment: Thanks for prompting me for a source - I didn't realise there was an entire Google Search Central on exactly this: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names Awkwardly it isn't very visible on related search terms. I cannot recall how I knew the format for Titles and can't find a source on it, however. It mentions it there but not how to format it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems related to the overall domain rating. I'd wager raising the E-E-A-T metrics via various off-page SEO tactics will start adding more weight to it. Also, having a Google Business profile should help as well.

Comment: Hi Gavin, Webmasters Stack Exchange is not the place to do your own off-page SEO. When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy. All links need to be directly related to the question at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).